# Coding a conversational AI which remembers previous context

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer, generative-model, language-model

I am trying to code a proper conversational AI which remembers previous context and answers accordingly (something like a micro ChatGPT). Additionally I want the AI to work on a custom knowledge base stored in a vector database like pinecone.

Are there any implementation references available ?